# Python: I need to put pair of point from a list into an array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to put pair of points into an array

```
for i in range(len(lon)):
    for j in range(len(lat)):
        tab = np.array([lon[i],lat[j]])
```

output:

```
array([1, 2])
```

But what I expect to have this: `array([1, 2],[1, 2],[1, 3],[1,2])`
The original values are:

```
lon = [1, 1, 1, 1] 
lat = [2, 2, 3, 2]
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: This is because the `tab` variable gets overwritten every time the loops passes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `tab` variable is being overwritten everytime in the loop. You can do it also simpler with a list comprehension:

```
lon = [1,1,1,1]
lat = [2,2,3,2]

output = [[lon[i],lat[i]] for i in range(len(lon))]
print(output)
```

This shows:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 2]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that's what I am looking for